# Which is the best logger for android appium automation?

Tags: android, testng, appium

I want to log all the testcases written using appium and testng can someone let me know which is the best logger I can use with appium for automation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you planning on doing with the logs ?

- Are you trying to add enriched information to your reports that basically capture all the chatty messages that were associated with every test method ? If that's the case, merely using `Reporter.log()` should suffice, because that will cause your messages (from your `@Test` annotated methods that is) to be logged on both the console and also tied to the test result of every `@Test` method, so that you can dump them on the reports (I believe the default reports that TestNG provides can also do this by default).
- If these logs are for debugging your framework related messages etc., then you might want to look at any of the logging frameworks such as [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) or just resort to using [Java utils logger](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html) (this comes part of the JDK and doesn't need you to add anything extra)